# How to create an Ionic project with existing www file

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a www file, which is part of an Ionic project. My question is: is there a way to create a new Ionic project with this www file so that I can display its functionalities? If there is a way, what Mac commands are involved?

Comment: No there is no.

Comment: Also this is bit strange why you are doing that or you want to upgrade old v1 app to v2?

Comment: create new ionic project -> copy www folder - > make required changes -> ionic run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new project. And Replace the www folder,it will work.